# numpy slicing the matrix based condition on the column python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
X = np.arange(1, 26).reshape(5, 5)
X[:,1:2] % 2 == 0
```

The conditions should only be applied to the second column
I want the whole matrix where the condition is true like

```
[array([[False,  True, False,  False, False],
       [ False, False,  False, False,  False],
       [False,  True, False,  False, False],
       [ False, False,  False, False,  False],
       [False,  True, False,  False, False]])]
```

It's giving the error
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 5 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

Comment: ```X=[X[::] % 2 == 0]``` then ```print(X)``` is what you want?

Comment: X is a 5x5 matrix, but X[:,1:2] is a 1x5 matrix. Their shapes are different, so the error occurred.

Comment: Please state your intended result as well, which elements of `X` do you expect to see, and in what shape.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(1, 26).reshape(5, 5)
X=[X[::] % 2 == 0]
print(X)
```

Output

```
[array([[False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole matrix where the condition is true. You can simply do this

```
X % 2 == 0
```

If you want to get the first column  where condition is true then

```
X[:, 1:2] % 2 ==0
```